# Visual Studio 2010 hangs on debug start for a minute or two

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, debugging

VS2010 hangs for several minutes after debug starts, after that debugging continues as usual. I have no idea what it's doing, Process Explorer says the debugged process is in suspended state during that hang and Visual Studio doesn't seem to write anything to disk except a few kB at the end of the hang.

There was no such hang for over eight months in any of my projects, it started yesterday.

**UPD:** Resetting all settings cured a lot of problems including this hang. I still don't know what it was, but resetting works magic.

Comment: @AnthonySottile XNA game

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed this as well and have determined that one of the causes is any code that uses interrupts or timers. Allegro 4.x (no comment on 5.x as I have not used it yet) is a big offender. Simply including and calling the global initialization method for the timer routines will cause this to happen.

Comment: Can it be a `Stopwatch` from `System.Diagnostics`? I can't test it now, it's not happening all the time.

Comment: @user1306322 Did you add code like that "yesterday" when it started?

Comment: Maybe, this week definnitely. Gonna comment it for some time now.